# Extjs drag and drop issue

Tags: extjs, drag

I am using ExtJS drag and drop and trying to make my own portal but I have a strange behaviour in a special case.

When you take this example : [Link](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/extjs4-mvc-portal/)

If i click on the header "Portlet 2" without dragging, I have this:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQigD.png)

I have no idea how to solve this...

EDIT :

It happens only on the first click. If you click on the header the fisrt time, you will have this problem. The second one, the "ghost" of the panel will be under the man panel (I want this behaviour on each time).

Comment: On what browser ? I couldn't reproduce the problem on Chrome 37 in Windows 8.1 64

Comment: IE 11.0.96 and Firefox 32.0. You only click on the header of the widget and you will have this behaviour (no drag).